# Xamarin.Forms - HttpClient GetAsync or PostAsync sometimes takes too long

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms and I am using HttpClient GetAsync and PostAsync to make calls to an api, my problem is the client is complaining that the application is too slow when it makes an api call. Is there anyways I can speed up this process or is there another faster way to call an api? Here is an example method:

```
public async Task<List<SubCatClass>> GetSubCategories(int category)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("category", category.ToString())
            });

            var response = await client.PostAsync(string.Format("https://exmample.com/api/index.php?action=getSubCategories"), content);

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            List<SubCatClass> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SubCatClass>>(responseString);

            return items;

        }
```

And here is how I am calling it.

```
await webService.GetSubCategories(item.categoryid);
```

The api I have full control over the code (PHP) and the server.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I called the api in postman and here was the results

[image]

Comment: "too slow when it makes an api call" is a pretty useless description of the problem.  How slow is "too" slow?  Is it consistently slow?  Or only sometimes?  Are they using WiFi or cell?  How good is their network?  How large are the requests/responses?  Is the server running on some crappy shared host?  Are you monitoring the server for responsiveness?  If I were you the first thing I would do is instrument my app to gather hard data on what "too slow" means, as well as ensure I have monitors setup on my server to correlate client requests with.

Comment: I am using a hostgator shared host, it is consistently slow, about 10 seconds per a request he is claiming, I would say 5-7 seconds max. They are using Wifi from screenshots I see full bars.

Comment: if you try the same API calls from a desktop using Postman or they also slow?  Have you looked at your server logs?

Comment: Just updated my question

Comment: more helpful for sure, although I still think it will be opinion based. Test the app yourself and see the speed. work out how much data is being sent in the problematic API requests. The user will likely need to help you out by sending you diagnostics such as their internet speed latency etc. I don't think anyone here can provide an accurate answer, you will need to dig around to find the cause of this problem. You might find this article helpful in your search for a solution http://jonathanpeppers.com/Blog/improving-http-performance-in-xamarin-applications

Comment: What do you expect us to tell you?  Have you even validated the performance issue using your own device?  Or are you just taking the client's word for it?  As I said in my first comment, you need to instrument your app and gather data first.

Comment: Yes I have tested in on my end and I get the same result.

Comment: Great, so have you profiled your code to see exactly what part is slow?

Comment: I guess what I am looking for, is there an alternative to HttpClient so I don't have await the results

Comment: @Jason profiled?

Comment: yes, use the Stopwatch class or something similar to figure out which part of your code is slow.  You are assuming it is the PostAsync but you don't have any evidence.  Look at the corresponding server logs to see how long the server takes to respond.

Comment: One issue is that you should NEVER create an HttpClient per call.  That way leads to socket exhaustion.   Create one HttpClient and reuse it.  async/await is a more efficient way of doing communications, a non-async/await version will take just as long to complete.

Comment: I had a similar issue some months ago with Xamarin Forms. The HttpResponseMessage implements the IDisposable interface and I did not dispose them like you. After some requests (the amount of requests was different) the HttpClient made really strange things. Therefore you should to dispose the HttpResponseMessage.

Comment: 1) *"is there an alternative to HttpClient"* - No. That isn't the problem - its how you use it. Start with what @Neil said - you do `new HttpClient()` inside that method. Instead create it ONCE when app starts. May take a second or two on the FIRST call (I make a dummy call to a trivial API, on a background thread, to **"warm up"** the connection.) 2) *"10 seconds per a request"* - as Jason said, you need to find out where that time goes. What user thinks of as "one request" might be **several "round trips"** to the server, in your code. Find out exactly where the time is going.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [ModernHttpClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/modernhttpclient-updated/), it will increase your speed than using default by Xamarin